# Refer to page number containing a passage of normal text

Tags: cross-referencing

I would like to cross-reference the page number of a passage of normal text.  The text is not a title, float, or list item.  Is there a (hopefully simple) way to do this in LaTeX?

Comment: just use `\label{whatever}` at the start of the text, and `\pageref{whatever}`

Comment: That just shook my world.  I always thought that the label was bound to a caption, float, or list item.  Hence, I thought that `\pageref{...}` would return the page of the caption, float, or list item.  As it turns out, `\nameref{...}` is bound that way, but `\pageref{...}` returns the page on which the label sits.  Did you want to post that as the answer?  You answer many questions here, so this might be more of an annoyance than a way to properly get credit where it is due, but I feel that if I offered to do it for you, it wouldn't be right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `\label{whatever}` at the start of the text, and `\pageref{whatever}`